# What is the name of the figure consisting of a slow revolution around longitudinal axis?

Tags: terminology, aerobatics, maneuver

*"An airplane performing one slow revolution around its longitudinal axis is performing one of these..."*

This was a clue on [Jeopardy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!) today. The contestant responded with, "What is a barrel roll?" which I contend is incorrect. But he earned $2000 for it.

My response would have been: "What is an *aileron* roll?" Is he correct, am I correct, or are we both correct?

Answer (score 2):

### What is an [Aileron Roll](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/26175/12720)?

---

You are correct, but should we really expect that level of precision from the entertainment business or the media?

Comment: I have lost all faith in Alex Trebek [shakes head in disappointment]

Comment: To be fair, a slow aileron roll executed by a slower, lower performance aircraft will also not be merely a revolution about the aircraft's longitudinal axis since a true aileron roll involves maneuvering to maintain altitude.

Comment: As long the longitudinal axis stays with the aircraft (as every sane pilot will strive for), any roll will be correct since it does not exclude other manouevres.