# If pilot use rudder to roll the aircraft at high AOA in the F4 Phantom then one aileron from one wing and one spoiler from other will be deflected?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, military, pilot-technique, aerobatics

I have heard that the F4 Phantom pilots can make barrel rolls at lower speed /higher AOA. They use only rudder deflection and keep the stick column centered (left /right wise)-only pull onto the belly to have the G's- to prevent adverse yaw effects. Does the spoiler on top of the wing move during the maneuver if the aileron stay neutral? The way it works for level rolls is : one side aileron deflected down but the other one is not (there is some slat(spoiler) on the other wing to assist the aileron down deflection. Is there a built in type of assistant like ailerons - rudder interconnection to help maneuvering? Or do the wings remain clean with no deflection of the control surface?

[image]

> of course it depends upon the situation and the specific fighter. when maneuvering at high angles of attack and high G, I always used solely aft stick and rudder, never any aileron or spoilers input. Sometimes I would use full rudder, all the way to the stops. Other times, not so much.

Comment: "When the F4 Phantom pilots makes barrel rolls at higher AOA, they use only rudder and keep the stick column centered."
Where does that come from ? It seems highly confusing to me, are you sure you didn't mix things up ?

Comment: I'm sure. There's two ways to do that :1 the traditional way - pull up then deflection of the stick  left or right and a bit of rudder, this is for higher speed or lower AOA. 2the pull up, stick in middle (not letting stick to slip out - left or right - by squeezing the knees together,- this was tell me by  a pilot-), but pulling toward your belly and pushing the rudder. This is for low speed and subsequent higher AOA. My question is not about that, it is about the aircraft surfaces deployment when the only rudder and pulling from elevators.

Comment: The second option you're describing is not a barrel roll but a snap roll which is actually a spin carrying a lot of forward speed.

Comment: I don't think he's describing a snap roll.  A swept wing with dihedral tips will certainly exhibit aerodynamic coupling between yaw (or more properly sideslip) and roll, and this effect will be most pronounced at high angles-of-attack.  Needs to be developed into a proper answer, but I'd have to find appropriate sources as I'm no expert on the F-4.

Comment: where does that image come from? and that citation?

Comment: The first thing you need to fix, which may get some of the DV's removed, is the idea that the slat is a surface on top of the wing. That's not what a slat is. The deflected surface shown in your photo is a spoiler or spoileron. I don't know whether the F-4 used differential spoiler deflection (i.e. spoillerons) as part of the roll control system. Your basic question seems to be, in part, whether surfaces on the wings automatically deflected whenever the rudder was deflected; the answer is almost certainly "no"

Comment: Yet your idea that rudder inputs should be used for roll control in the F-4 at high angles-of-attack may be a sound one, despite the apparent skepticism of other ASE members. See for example https://simworksstudios.com/knowledge-base/f4bn-chapters/general-information-specifications.html . Yes, it is just a link from a sim (game) page, but similar sources might be found in reference to the real thing. And it's pretty clear that a "snap roll" is NOT what is being referenced here. Note the reference to aerodynamic coupling between slip and roll in the link

Comment: Also, yes, the citation at the end of your question needs a source. Is it from an experienced military flier? A gamer? ?? PS The F-4 did in fact have slats at least in some models but that's not what is shown in your photo. And they were certainly not automatically opened whenever the rudder was moved. As to whether they ever opened differentially-- probably not, they were probably hydraulically driven and always opened together at a certain airspeed or angle-of-attack, or perhaps at a certain flaps setting, etc.

Comment: Probably enough there for a real answer but I'd like to give him a chance to fix the question first  PS I see an edit has already been made, good-- more later.

Comment: quiet flyer, Yes my mistake it is called spoiler. The citation is from a real pilot, not sim buff. But you wrong about the symetrical deployment of the spoilers. Just look at the F14Tomcat, F4E, orG.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that spoilers always deploy symmetrically.  I'm saying that I don't know whether differential spoiler (spoileron) deflection was used on the F-4 (I'd guess probably it was, but connected to aileron inputs only, not connected to rudder inputs), and I'm also saying that the actual SLATS were probably not allowed to move differentially and were certainly not physically interconnected either to aileron inputs or rudder inputs.

Comment: PS just as an added point of reference, in some older aircraft such as Bf-109 the actual SLATS were purely aerodynamically driven and sometimes one would open when the other was still closed.  I highly doubt this was the case with the F-4 though.  That might help make my comments more clear.

Comment: Live aside slats, from the front of the wings (leading edge), for F4are symetrical deployed. Anyway for F18 Legacy Hornet if rolling then they would be asymmetric  deflected just for to know about it. My question was summarised by you. Maybe in sim are some filters to cancel (dumping) the rolling momentum from the tail. That is why I asked.

Comment: The F86 Sabre, A4 Skyhawk they have same gravitational leading edges deployment (slats),jamming from time to time. My guess is that the yaw moment (drifting) will do that jamming.

Answer (score 4):

A Barrel Roll is a maneuver where the aircraft flight path follows what would be the surface of a huge horizontal barrel in the sky. To do this you of course need to roll the aircraft. To roll the Phantom, no matter what maneuver you are attempting, requires that you create differential lift on the wings. (more lift on the up-moving wing than on the down-moving wing). At low angle of Attack (AOA), in any model of F-4, you use the ailerons/spoilers to do this. At higher AOA, the ailerons would induce adverse yaw, and therefore you need to create this differential lift by yawing the aircraft with the rudder (since it's a swept wing aircraft). As AOA increases above 10-12 units, the pilot needs to blend in more and more rudder, and less aileron, until at high AOA (19 units in early non-slatted aircraft like F-4B/C/D), he is using rudder exclusively. In later slatted aircraft (USAF F-4Es, F-4Js, USN F-4J/S, etc.) this effect was somewhat mitigated by the slats (they energized the airflow over the top of the wing), and the pilot could use some aileron throughout the AOA range, (but still less and less as AOA increased), all the way to 25 units AOA.

As to your other question about slat deployment, this happened automagically, based on AOA, at about 12-14 units AOA as I recall. And then would retract when AOA fell below 10-12 units... No pilot input was necessary.

So, in the execution of a Barrel Roll in the F-4, starting at 450 KIAS and low AOA at the entry point, the aircraft would climb and descend 4-5000 feet, and  slow to somewhere between 200-250 KIAS and higher AOA at the high point, and then accelerate back to 450 KIAS and low AOA at the completion of the maneuver. As a result, the need for aileron and rudder to effect the roll continuously and gradually changed throughout the maneuver.

NOTE. (to address comment made in the question relating to photograph). The F-4's ailerons did move up slightly when the stick was deflected towards that wing, but at high AOA, the aerodynamic effect was negligible due to the wing blanking the airflow back there. SO the F-4 also had spoilers on the top of the wing that would deflect upwards as well, both to decrease the lift on the wing and cause a roll in that direction, and to add drag on that wing to balance the drag from the down aileron on the opposite wing. The control surface deflected on the upper wing in the photo is the spoiler, caused by the pilot pushing the stick to the left.

The following is from the USAF F-4E flight Manual:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pretend that not everyone here is a pilot. What is a "unit" of AoA? Is it a degree, some percentage of max elevator deflection, something else entirely?

Comment: In the F-4 AOA was displayed and referenced in all manuals and documents in arbitrary "unit"s, which represented the actual AOA angle. The relationship between AOA units and AOA degrees, or radians, or Milliradians was not specified. We were only taught the relationship between the units and the aerodynamic properties that the aircraft at various AOA values, Un-loaded (very low AOA) was 3-5 units, L/Dmax occurred at 10-12 units, Cl max (Max performance or approach AOA) occurred at 19.2 units (non-Slatted) and at 25 units (slatted). Stall (loss of directional control) occurred at 23/29 units.

Comment: ... and my apologies for not "pretending"... I've never been good at that... otherwise I might "pretend" that not everyone here was polite....  oh wait, they're not...

Comment: Thanks for the info. That strikes me as odd that they would use "units" and not something that people would come in with a basic understanding of. Most people can reasonably guestimate 15° or 30°, but 25 "units" has no built in human intuition point. OTOH, maybe that's why they went with it...

Comment: no worries, I added the explanation from the USAF F-4E flight Manual. It appears that the units, from 0 to 30 "units" represent angular rotation of the AOA probe from -10 to + 40 angular degrees. How that aligns with actual AOA is of course ALSO arbitrary, as it is a measurement taken from the arbitrary line of the mean aerodynamic chord (MAC) of the main wing.

Answer (score 1):

They are 3 different ways to roll an airplane:

First the **barrel roll** during which the airplane is flying normally, you are keeping positive g rate and using ailerons to induce the roll. The trajectory is making a wide spiral and you use rudder input to keep the symmetry of the flight.

Second the **aileron roll**, where the aircraft continues in a straight line and your airplane is almost rolling on itself, the roll rate is dependent on your ailerons input and you use rudder to displace the nose of the aircraft around the central axis by mostly crating lift when your roll position is equal to 90 or 270°.

[image: Barrel roll vs aileron roll]

Finally and that is what you are describing is the **snap roll or flick roll**. Which is basically a horizontal spin. flying low you simultaneously apply full rudder deflection and pull the yoke. This means you have high AOA and non symmetrical flow inducing a spin by stalling one of the wing. But you have enough forward momentum to continue in a straight line, thus making it looks like a roll. Once the snap roll initiated, some aileron might be needed to either keep or stop the rotation but as for a normal spin this might change from one aircraft to another.

Comment: True, but I asked about the F4 only-there's something ( a system maybe that couples the rudder with slats)? That's all?

Comment: A mechanical link between rudder and any control surface on the wing doesn't make sens as they are supposed to work around two different axis. What exist are yaw damper that replace rudder input in coordinated turn and electronics. New military aircraft have combined control surface deflection to increase maneuverability and the flight performances of the aircraft. But that's the onboard computer doing it and I don't think this apply to the F4

Comment: I asked because in some simulator the opposite slat lifted a bit(3degrees) and along with the aileron if  rudder deflection to cancel any little disturbance from the level flight.

Comment: I think the categorization of rolls into 3 types is somewhat arbitrary.  For what you are calling the "aileron roll", you are saying that the rudder is used to create sideways lift at 90 degrees and 270 degrees.  Does it not also follow that forward stick should be used to create negative (skyward) lift at 180 degrees?  But the diagram you posted doesn't show the aircraft in a nose-high attitude when inverted, nor does it show it in a nose-high attitude at 270 degrees.  (The attitude at 90 degees isn't illustrated.) (ctd)

Comment: (....ctd)  I think most pilots would consider an aileron-roll to be a positively-loaded maneuver, just with a higher roll rate, less time to complete, and less variation in G-load and aircraft attitude and trajectory than a "barrel roll".  Meanwhile your description of an "aileron roll" really sounds more like a "slow roll"-- which in theory could be completed at any roll rate, slow or fast, but the key point being that the aerodynamic force vector / G-loading continually points in the skyward/ earthward direction, rather than "upward"/ downward in the pilot's reference frame.

Comment: For more on the same theme see https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/66561/34686 , which is an answer that I forgot I had written but just now searched up.

Comment: @quietflyer it all depend on the aicraft speed, the diagram is good for an extra330 where you don't even need rudder during the roll, due to higher speed and roll rate. But in a slower airplane the Cap-10 for example you need rudder on the side and forward stick while inverted. The -1g you will experience it in both aircraft just not for the same amount of time. At least it is the strict definition I know from my aerobatic flying. The barrel roll can be done with any aircraft if your a good enough pilot but not the aileron roll.

Comment: Yet another variation-- I took some dual aerobatic lessons in a glider, where we did what we called "aileron rolls" (I think) or maybe just "rolls" and we definitely did push the stick forward to create negative G when inverted, but we used the rudder only for coordination (to keep the yaw string / ball centered) and not to create any sideways lift.  The roll rate wasn't real fast, it was a purpose-designed aerobatic glider but I'm sure the roll rate was slower than say a Cap-10.  Lots of possible variations on the theme it seems to me...  Oh well probably shouldn't have typed so much...

Comment: Well... you mixed a bit both of the solution there and I see two reasons. A glider don't fly on the side, in opposite to modern aerobatic aircraft that have fuselage lift and then they don't really like non-symmetric flight condition. To initiate the barrel roll you start to pull straight to put the nose up 30° and then roll, keeping the yoke pulled to ensure positive g rating all the way. But you end up with a nose down attitude: In aileron roll your nose is actually making a circle on the horizon and the slower you fly the bigger the circle. But most important your altitude remain constant.